# Converting VS2005 Web Service Project to VS2010

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, asmx

I inherited a web service that was installed and forgotten about years ago.  Now we need to change it, but it's built in VS2005, and all I have is vs2010.  When I load the project, it automatically attempts to convert, but fails on these errors:

`The operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the path specified.` (no information on what file it was looking for)

`Could not find the server 'http://localhost/<myproject>/<myproject>.csproj' on the local machine. Creating a virtual directory is only supported on the local IIS server.` (I don't understand why a setting like that should prevent the project from loading/ connecting, this is clearly a config thing.  Besides, I'm using IIS Express, which uses different ports, so that'll never work.)

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an opportunity to manually tweak these problems in VS2010.  It simply won't load the project.

How can I force this to load in VS so I can fix this in a reasonably sane manner?  Maybe run VS2010 in some compatibility mode, or if there's an app I can use to convert this, or if someone has some experience in doing this sort of thing, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still have VS2005 around? Open the project in VS2005 and look at the project settings. See if the project is set up to use the local IIS server.

If it is, then change it to use the Visual Studio Development Server and save the project. Convert it to VS2010 and you should be able to open it (still using the Development Server).

Then, change the settings to use IIS Express.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never had VS2005.  This code was built by a group that split off from ours about 4 years ago.  To date, it has not needed any modification and it just worked, so it was no big deal.  Now, of course, it's a big deal.

Comment: Then perhaps you should install IIS, open the project in VS2010, then change the settings to IIS Express.

Comment: Hmm.  That is a possibility.  Do you know how to find out which file it's missing?

Comment: What makes you think a file is missing?

Comment: `The operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: yes it was, but it went away when I worked out the other error.  Ultimately, I configured IIS Express to listen on port 80 for the ASMX page, and I was able to successfully convert the application to C# .NET 4.  Thanks for the suggestion.